# How to fix palm detection in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, 17.04

I have had this problem since Ubuntu 16.04. The palm detection simply does not work. 
I tried running commands mentioned in [this](https://stevenkohlmeyer.com/fixing-palm-detect-ubuntu-14-04/) article but to no effect.

Output of `xinput`:

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of `xinput list-props 11:

```
    Device 'DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (140):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (267): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (268):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (269):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (270):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (271):  49, 1180, 50, 879
    Synaptics Finger (272): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (273):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (274):   67
    Synaptics Tap Durations (275):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (276):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (277):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (278):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (279):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (280): -30, -30
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (281): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (282):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (283): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.129870, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (284):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (285):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (286):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (287): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (288):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (289): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (290):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (291): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (292):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (293): 1
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (294):    5, 5
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (295): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (296):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (297): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (298):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (299):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (300):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (301):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (302): 12, 12
    Synaptics Area (303):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (304):  614, 0, 761, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (305): 7, 7
    Device Product ID (264):    1739, 30143
    Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event10"
```

Contents of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`:

```
# Match on all types of devices but tablet devices and joysticks
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection


Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
    MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
    MatchIsTablet "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Now please add output of `xinput list-props 11`

Comment: @Pilot6 Done. Palm detection is set to 1.

Comment: It looks OK. You can change `/dev/input/event*` to `/dev/input/event10` in the touchpad section of this file. But I suspect you've changed some other `conf` file there.

Comment: If you do a fresh install of 17.04, `libinput` will be used. If you do  a fresh install of 16.04, libinput can also be enabled easily. But you changed something that is hard to guess.

Comment: @Pilot6 Is re-installins Ig the only way? As fair as I remember, I have installed Ubuntu many times and this was the problem every time.

Comment: It is not the only way, but I don't know why libinput does not work in your case. It works for me.

Comment: @Pilot6 Is it okay if I install 16.04/16.10 instead of 17.04?

Comment: @Pilot6 Re-installed. Still the same problem and still no `libinput`.

Comment: And what if remove `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`?

Comment: @Pilot6 There's a new issue now. `xinput` now shows `libinput` instead of Synaptics but I can't right click with two fingers, tap to click or enable natural scrolling. Not with System Preferences, not with `dconf-editor`.

Comment: Oh, it is easy. Add `Option "Tapping" "True"` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` to the touchpad section before `EndSection`. `Option "NaturalScrolling" "True"` at the same place will enable natural scrolling.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks. That fixed it. But why wasn't this editable with other GUI tools?

Comment: GUI tools don't support libinput yet.

Comment: @Pilot6 Okay. Thanks again. Can finally use Ubuntu now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synaptics user space driver is not very good in palm detection.

In Ubuntu 17.04 `libinput` is the default user space driver. It is not istalled for some reason.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

to install it. Then reboot.

Tapping may be disabled by default. Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` to look this way:

```
# Match on all types of devices but tablet devices and joysticks
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection


Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "True"
    Option "NaturalScrolling" "True"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
    MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
    MatchIsTablet "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

to enable tapping and natural scrolling.

Comment: Do I have to enable any repositories? It says `unable tp locate package`.

Comment: I fixed a typo in the package name.

Comment: It says, `xserver-xorg-input-libinput is already the newest version (0.25.0-0ubuntu1).`

Comment: This is weird. `libinput` has a priority. You probably changed some config files and it got disabled. Please edit your question and add the contents of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` file. And also remove everything you configured before.

Comment: any solution to palm detection yet?